# Adding text to froala in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, froala

I have a froala editor that I wish to add some text to. So far I've tried using innerhtml:

**HTML**

```
<div id="notesDiv" #divvy [froalaEditor]="options" [(froalaModel)]="editorContent">
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
@ViewChild('divvy') divvy:ElementRef;
toAppend: string = '<p>Hi there!</p>';
this.divvy.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.toAppend;
```

The problem here is that while it appends the html, it removes the editor completely.

**What it does:**
[image]

**What I want:**
[image]

In the documentation there is a method for this:

```
$('.selector').froalaEditor('html.set', '<p>My custom paragraph.</p>');
```

Is there a way to do this in angular4/typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this just by assigning the `editorContent` variable to something in typescript:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.editorContent = <p>Hello!</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the built in renderer angular class.

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer) {}

@ViewChild('divvy') divvy:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.divvy.nativeElement', insertAdjacentHTML' ['beforeend', '<div>Hello There</div>']);
```

}

Comment: I tried this, it just appended the 'Hello There' div at the bottom of my froala editor.